# Python: Save a file based on user input

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, pickle

I am attempting to save a file from a python tkinter window via a 'Save As' prompt. I have looked for a while now and cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for. I can successfully save the information to a file with a default name, and even can save it using a name the user inputs via input(), however, this is not what I am trying to do. I want the user to be able to click, 'Save As' and then when the prompt comes up, they enter in the file name and it saves as that name, I just cannot seem to find an answer anywhere. Here is my code at this point:

```
# Import Tkinter
from tkinter import *
import os
import pickle
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfile
from tkinter.messagebox import *

MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.geometry("600x400")
MainWindow.attributes("-alpha", 1)
MainWindow.title(string="Hours Log")
CurrentDirect=os.getcwd()

def FileSaveAs():
fname = asksaveasfile(initialdir=CurrentDirect ,filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))
if fname:
        try:
            print(fname)
            SH = SHVar.get()
            SM = SMVar.get()
            SAP = SAPVar.get()
            EH = EHVar.get()
            EM = EMVar.get()
            EAP = EAPVar.get()
            DM = DMVar.get()
            DD = DDVar.get()
            DY = DYVar.get()
            DE = Description.get("1.0", END)
            AP = APVar.get()
            with open("filename.txt", 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([SH, SM, SAP, EH, EM, EAP, DM, DD, DY, DE, AP], f)

        except:
            showerror("FILE SAVE ERROR", "Error on Saving File!\n'%s'" % fname)
        return
```

I understand that the "filename.txt" is the name of the file to save to, however, how do I acquire the variable name from the prompt?

NOTE: There are no errors in this code, it runs fine with the rest of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asksaveasfilename` instead of `asksaveasfile` and `fname` instead of `"filename.txt"`.

```
  60   def asksaveasfile(self):
  61 
  62     """Returns an opened file in write mode."""
  63 
  64     return tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', **self.file_opt)
  65 
  66   def asksaveasfilename(self):
  67 
  68     """Returns an opened file in write mode.
  69     This time the dialog just returns a filename and the file is opened by your own code.
  70     """
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I simply changed the lines from:
`fname = asksaveasfile(...`
`with open("filename.txt", 'wb') as f:`

to:
`fname = asksaveasfilename(...`
`with open(filename+".txt", 'wb') as f:`

It's always the simpe ones that get me.